# Variable into another variable getting “undefined”

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, undefined

In this code, the variable "link" is giving "undefined". I don't have a clue of what is the cause. This is my code:

HTML, 1st try:

```
<html>
    <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a onclick="doSom()">Click here!</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (w/ jQuery), 1st try:

```
var link;
var testing="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
function doSom(){
    link="http://www.google.com";
    $('p').html(testing);
}
```

HTML, 2nd try:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a onclick="doSom('www.google.com.br')">Click here!</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (w/ jQuery), 2nd try:

```
var link;
var testando="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
function doSom(link){
    $('p').html(testing);
}
```

The variable "link" is not giving its value at the code above, remaining "undefined".

This is the inicial code, that works (but I'm optimizing it):

HTML from 1st try;

JavaScript (w/ jQuery):

```
var link;
var testingi="Testing this <a href='";
var testingii="'>variable</a> here.";
function doSom(link){
    $('p').html(testingi+link+testingii);
}
```

I think it's totally unnecessary to declare 2 variables for only one sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem boils down to the fact that you're trying to *use* the `link` variable before you've *initialized* it.

```
var link; // By default, this is `undefined`
var testing="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
// Your `testing` link will now contain the string `undefined`
function doSom(){
    link="http://www.google.com";
    // Since you don't update `testing` it still has "undefined" in it somewhere
    $('p').html(testing);
}
```

The solution: wait to build your `testing` link until after you've initialized your `link` variable.

Comment: How silly was I. But see, my variable "testing" has a looot of code, which is why I'm trying to shorten it.

There's a code to update the variable without have to write it all again?

Comment: ES6 template strings would make this a little cleaner (but IE doesn't support them) - `\`Testing this <a href="${link}">variable</a> here.\``

Comment: IE is not a problem, I'm showing a message to change the browser. :P

Thanks, man. Ended a whole month doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the link before it has a value, hence undefined. define the string afterwards.

See here:

```
var link;
 ----  this is empty at definition !!! var testing="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
 function doSom(){
 link="http://www.google.com";
$('p').html(testing);
}
```

Do this:

```
var link;
var testing;
function doSom(){
link="http://www.google.com";
testing ="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
$('p').html(testing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code "tentativa 1", the reason link is undefined is that you inserted it into the string test before your assigned a value to link.

Change

```
var link;
var testing="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
function doSom(){
    link="http://www.google.com";
    $('p').html(testing);
}
```

to

```
var link;
function doSom(){
    link="http://www.google.com";
var testing="Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.";
    $('p').html(testing);
}
```

and it will work.

Same with "2nd try". Move your string definition for test (and rename it to be correct) and it should work fine.

I'm guessing that "JavaScript (w/ jQuery):" works ok.

You are right, though, you do not need to define those variables. That is not why it works correctly in the last example. It is because you are referring to 'link' after it has been defined.

A better way to do it (avoid defining useless variables and reference 'link' after it has been defined is to change your html assignment to look like this:

```
    link="http://www.google.com";
    $('p').html("Testing this <a href=\""+link+"\">variable</a> here.");
```

Your main take away should be that putting a variable into a string does not maintain a reference to the variable. The variable's value at the moment it is included into the string is final. You must not include it in the final string assignment until after it has been assigned its value.